# Scala: why doesn't List[=>Int] work?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I've been working on learning the ins and outs of scala, and recently I've come across something I'm curious about.

As I understand, if I want to pass a block of code that is effectively lazily evaluated to a function, (without evaluating it on the spot) I could type:

```
def run(a: =>Int):Int = {...}
```

In this sense, the function run receives a block of code, that is yet to be evaluated, which it evaluates and returns the computed Int of. I then tried to extend this idea to the List data structure. Typing:

```
def run(a: List[=>Int]) = {...}
```

This however, returns an error. I was wondering why this is disallowed. How, other than by this syntax can I pass a list of unevaluated blocks of code?

Answer (score 10):

`=>Int` is the syntax for by name parameters. `=>Int` is not a type, so it can't be used as a parameter to `List`. However, `()=>Int` is a type. It's the type of nullary functions that return `Int`. So this works:

```
def run(a: List[()=>Int]) = {...}
```

Comment: Ah! That should do it, thanks for the answer Kim. By the by, does the JVM put an anonymous function, such as the ones being stored in the above list, in the heap?

Comment: Yes, they are stored on the heap.

Answer (score 5):

by-name parameter is not a first-class type in Scala.

`List[()=>Int]` is one of the solution. otherwise, You can use following `Lazy` data structure.

- https://gist.github.com/1164885
- https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v6.0.4/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Name.scala#L99-107
- https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.0.0-M7/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Name.scala#L37-L60
- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/transform/Transforms.scala#L9-23
- https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/v0.12.1/compile/api/SafeLazy.scala
- https://github.com/okomok/ken/blob/0.1.0/src/main/scala/com/github/okomok/ken/Lazy.scala
- https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1-RC1/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/Util.scala#L3-L11

Comment: Another option is to use `Stream`, which is also a lazy data structure.